# How do I install latest latte-dock development version 0.10?

Tags: kubuntu, latte-dock

I want to install latte-dock latest development version(0.10) but I can't find it on the internet. I know this version is not stable but I want to install it at soon.

I'm using Kubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a way to install it and it's work so if you wan't to install it in Kubuntu and KDE Neon Follow this way:

```
git clone https://github.com/KDE/latte-dock.git

sudo apt install cmake extra-cmake-modules qtdeclarative5-dev libqt5x11extras5-dev libkf5iconthemes-dev libkf5plasma-dev libkf5windowsystem-dev libkf5declarative-dev libkf5xmlgui-dev libkf5activities-dev build-essential libxcb-util-dev libkf5wayland-dev git gettext libkf5archive-dev libkf5notifications-dev libxcb-util0-dev libsm-dev libkf5crash-dev libkf5newstuff-dev libxcb-shape0-dev libxcb-randr0-dev libx11-dev libx11-xcb-dev

export CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/opt/xwi

sudo apt install libxcb-randr0-dev

sudo apt install kirigami2-dev
```

Then go into where you clone the latte dock "By default in the Home folder" and run this command in there:

```
sh install.sh
```

Comment: don't forget this is the way to install it in 20.4  because in 21.10 you just need to follow normal installing ways