# Problem installing latte dock master from git

Tags: command-line, kubuntu, git, latte-dock

Hi guys i ask in my last question [have i can install latte dock development version of latte](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1304706/how-do-i-install-latest-latte-dock-development-version-0-10/1304709?noredirect=1#comment2219063_1304709) and now i find development file but i can install it please help me

this is [link](https://github.com/KDE/latte-dock) of development package in git and i download and run it with installation.md file but in "Building and Installing" stage i have some problems for run `sh install.sh` after i run this code in file folder i see some errors like this:
[image]

You can see i use `sh install.sh` and use `bash install.sh` but it's not work

"I use Kubuntu"

help me and tell me what is that and have i can install latte dock master on my Kubuntu

Comment: Try `bash install.sh` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a way to install it and it's work so if you wan't to install it in Kubuntu and KDE Neon Follow this way:

```
git clone https://github.com/KDE/latte-dock.git

sudo apt install cmake extra-cmake-modules qtdeclarative5-dev libqt5x11extras5-dev libkf5iconthemes-dev libkf5plasma-dev libkf5windowsystem-dev libkf5declarative-dev libkf5xmlgui-dev libkf5activities-dev build-essential libxcb-util-dev libkf5wayland-dev git gettext libkf5archive-dev libkf5notifications-dev libxcb-util0-dev libsm-dev libkf5crash-dev libkf5newstuff-dev libxcb-shape0-dev libxcb-randr0-dev libx11-dev libx11-xcb-dev

export CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/opt/xwi

sudo apt install libxcb-randr0-dev

sudo apt install kirigami2-dev
```

Then go into where you clone the latte dock "By default in the Home folder" and run this command in there:

```
sh install.sh
```

If when you run `sh install.sh` it's tell you `mkdir: cannot create directory "Build": File exists` you need to go in the folder latte dock clone it there and Delete the "Build" folder in there

Comment: This way about to install latte dock 0.10 Development version