# I have an error when instaling latte-dock 0.10

Tags: 20.04, kubuntu, lts, cmake, latte-dock

when I try to install latte-dock 0.10 by my [own guides](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1304706/how-do-i-install-latest-latte-dock-development-version-0-10) I see this error:

```
/home/amir/latte-dock/app/settings/viewsdialog/viewscontroller.cpp:47:10: fatal error: KIO/OpenUrlJob: No such file or directory

   47 | #include <KIO/OpenUrlJob>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [app/CMakeFiles/latte-dock.dir/build.make:974: app/CMakeFiles/latte-dock.dir/settings/viewsdialog/viewscontroller.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1898: app/CMakeFiles/latte-dock.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:141: all] Error 2
```

I never see that before because I reinstall my Kubuntu and in the previous Kubuntu I install latte dock with my [own guides](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1304706/how-do-i-install-latest-latte-dock-development-version-0-10) truly without this problem and it's a new problem

Answer (score 3):

You have to start with getting build-dependencies of [packaged 0.9.11 version](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=latte-dock): enable Source Code repositories (*deb-src*) in Software & Updates (`software-properties-gtk`) and then execute

```
sudo apt-get build-dep latte-dock
```

Then proceed with compilation.

But it will not work because of missed `KIO/OpenUrlJob`. It is only available for [20.10 and newer Ubuntu versions in `libkf5kio-dev` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=groovy&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=KIO%2FOpenUrlJob).

So you have to use packaged 0.9.11 version of Latte Dock. Install it as simple as `sudo apt-get install latte-dock` .

Comment: But version 20.10 is crashed so much and I don't want to upgrade from 20.4 to 20.10

Comment: Is there any where to install it without installing 20.10?

Comment: Staying on LTS is always good idea. On 20.04 LTS you can try to install newer version of dock from https://launchpad.net/~rikmills/+archive/ubuntu/latte-dock?field.series_filter=focal .

Comment: But the files in this link is not version 0.10

Comment: It is only numbers. You give them too much attention :)

Comment: I love you bro my problem is fixed  with this link I love you so much wohoooooooo :)